# Overriding Drupal.ajax.prototype is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, 9

I am trying to override Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend like this:

```
(function($) {
  // In mymodule.js, which appears after ajax.js in the page build
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function(xmlhttprequest, options) {
    console.log('overridden!')
  }
})(jQuery);
```

The file that contains the code is listed below core's ajax.js in the page's source, yet it's the console.log I put inside core's ajax.js beforeSend that is showing up.

What else is to it? Has anything been changed in Drupal? Using version 9.3. Can't override any of those functions.

Comment: Did you also pass in the 'Drupal' object?

Comment: I even passed 'jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings'.

Comment: Isn't `ajax` spelled `Ajax`?

Comment: Wow, actually there are both "ajaxes", and the one I need is, indeed, spelled 'Ajax'. Thank you! Can't mark the comment as the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two javascript objects:

1. `Drupal.ajax`
2. `Drupal.Ajax`

You have to override the prototypes in `Drupal.Ajax`. For each Ajax object declared in Drupal settings an instance of it will then be stored in  `Drupal.ajax.instances`.

Comment: Do you know where this is documented? I looked around a little and I mostly just find answers to questions like this, with information like this, but no linked source.